# LINQ using group by and ascending order

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables `attendancelogs` and `employees` with following structure;

Attendance Logs Table:

```
Attendancelogs

Att_Id
Registeration_Id
DateTime
CheckType
```

Employees Table:

```
Employees
Id
Emp_Id
Enroll_Id
```

Now what I'm trying is to write a query that will fetch all the records from the `attendancelogs` that have their `CheckType` value as "Pending" and the `Registeration_Id` being equal to the `Enroll_Id` in the `Employees` table `OrderByAcsending` on the `DateTime`. In other words, get all the records from the attendancelogs table whos `RegistrationId` is equal to the `Enroll_Id` in the `Employees` table and their CheckType`is Pending and they should be orderbyascending according to the`DateTime`

What I tried was an ugly way of using `foreach`

```
//some method that populates a list
 ICollection<AttendanceLog> lstMachineInfo = manipulator.GetLogData(objZkeeper2, machineNum);
 List<Employee> empList = db.Employees.ToList();
  foreach (var emp in empList)
                        {
 var empLogs = lstMachineInfo.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == int.Parse(emp.EnrollNumber)).ToList();
 var prevDate = (from obj in empLogs select obj.Date).FirstOrDefault();
                            var prevDateTime = (from obj in empLogs select obj.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
//and so on
```

This obviously is very costly when it comes to performance and I have minimal knowledge of optimizing the queries.

Comment: I would suggest that you have at the documentation of linq and joins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code on list of Attendance and Employee

```
var result = from attendence in AttendenceList
                   orderby attendence.DateTime
                   join employee in EmployeeList on attendence.Registeration_Id equals employee.Enroll_Id into employeejoin
                   from employ in employeejoin
                   orderby attendence.DateTime ascending
                   where attendence.Registeration_Id == employ.Enroll_Id && attendence.CheckType == "Pending"
                   orderby attendence.DateTime ascending
                   select attendence;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
//You are building your query to get all att ordered by date
var query = (from emp in db.Employees
             join att in db.Attendancelogs 
                 on emp.EnrollNumber equals att.RegisterationId 
             where att.CheckType.ToLower() == "pending"
             select att)
             .OrderBy(att => att.DateTime);

//You fire the query
List<Attendancelogs> attList = query.ToList();
```